# Tap event is incorrectly fired when swiping a RadListView

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a RadListView that displays a list of items. In each item template I have a (tap) event that fires when tapping on the item, to redirect to the item details screen. However, for some reason whenever I swipe the RadListView vertically to traverse the list, it fires the (tap) event wherever I start swiping from and incorrectly redirects to the item details screen instead of just moving up or down the list.

```
<RadListView
        class="list transparent"
        [class.visible]="!data.loading"
        [visibility]="!data.loading ? 'visible' : 'collapse'"
        [items]="data.items"
        swipeActions="true"
        (itemSwipeProgressStarted)="onSwipeCellStarted($event)">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <StackLayout class="item" orientation="horizontal" (tap)="view(item)">
                <Image
                    [src]="item.photos?.length ? item.photos[0] : ''"
                    [visibility]="item.photos?.length ? 'visible' : 'collapse'">
                </Image>
                <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                    <Label
                        class="title"
                        [text]="item.address">
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>

        <GridLayout *tkListItemSwipeTemplate columns="*, auto">
            <StackLayout id="delete" col="1" (tap)="deleteRow($event)" class="delete">
                <Label class="fas" [text]="IconsEnum.trashAlt"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </RadListView>
```

I tried getting rid of the (tap) event and instead using the following on the RadListView:

```
multipleSelection="false" selectionBehavior="Press" (itemSelected)="itemSelected($event)"
```

That resolved the issue with swiping, however it introduced a new issue where it would only select an item every two taps instead of every swipe.

What is the proper way to select an item from a RadListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from @nativescript/ios 7.1.1 to 7.2.0 resolved this bug.